# Command line application to access Facebook information

Tags: facebook, api, command-line

I am interested in developing a command line application that:
- shows my wall messages;
- direct messages received;
- chat;
- friends currently online;

Does the API that Facebook has allow for this kind of thing?

Any references to documentation is well appreciated.

Comment: It has been done before .. check this link http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/